# Dropzonejs and Paperclip, url and paramName?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, dropzone.js

I don't understand what the `URL` and `paramName` should be if you're customizing the dropzone?

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false
$('#new_picture').dropzone
  url: '/projects'
  maxFilesize: 1
  paramName: 'project_images[photos]'
  addRemoveLinks: true
```

I'm pretty sure my paramName and url is wrong.

I have nested paperclip like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @project, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <div class='dropzone' id="new_picture">
    <div class="fallback">
      <%= file_field_tag "photos[]", multiple: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

## I have a project_image.rb

```
class ProjectImage < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :project
  has_attached_file :photo, 
                    :styles => { 
                        :large => "800x800>", 
                        :thumb => "150x150#" }, 
                    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  attachment :file

end
```

## my params looks like this in projects_controller.rb

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(
    :user_id,
    project_images_attributes: [:id, :project_id, :photo, :_destroy])
end
```

## Just to show what my create looks like

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save

      if params[:photos]
        params[:photos].each { |image|
          @project.project_images.create(photo: image)
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your `project` and `project_image` both has `photo`?

Comment: @Pavan I just had it in there because I was testing things out. it shouldn't be in there. I'll edit it out. The `:photo` came from when I did `rails g paperclip project_image photo`

Comment: Ok. In your form, you are not wrapping `file_field` with the `form object`. I understood why you given like that. So the `params` for `photos` will come in `params[:photos]`, so i guess `paramName: 'photos'` will work. If that doesn't work try `paramName: 'photos[]'`.

Comment: And also you have given `$('#new_picture').dropzone` if the `#new_picture` relate to `id` then your `form` should have an `id` as `new_picture`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `url` is specified when your `form` has no action defined. I have used `dropzone.js` like this:

```
= form_tag new_drag_drop_photo_path, method: :post, class: "dropzone form-horizontal", id: "media-dropzone", :authenticity_token => true do
  = file_field_tag "photo", multiple: true
```

Now when the photo is dragged and dropped in my dropzone field then it will be sent to this action defined like this:

```
Started POST "/new_drag_drop_photo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-24 10:55:04 +0530
Processing by PhotosController#new_drag_drop_photo as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rmp7BwrEoa7iCesuPifQm60YwAemDCfq6t7soQ==", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f6b78ab5190 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150724-4280-1obqg7k.jpg>, @original_filename="bridal-dresses-4.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"bridal-dresses-4.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}
```

So now as you are not using the `form`, instead you are using a `div` that is why you need to define `url` where the photos will be sent when dragged. This would be a `json` request and `dropzone` will expect a `json` response from the server. So you will need a controller's action like I have specified it:

```
def new_drag_drop_photo
    @photo = Photo.new(image: params[:file], name: params[:file].original_filename.split('.')[0])
    if @photo.save!
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json{ render :json => @photo }
      end
    else
      render json: { error: @photo.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
    end
  end
```

Now here I am taking the `filename` from file itself. And when you provide that in dropzone configuration like this: `paramName: 'project_images[photos]'` then it will pass this name when the file is sent to the controller's action. As you have used nested form here I too have used that but I have used some jquery to add photo_ids to it. So what I do is I get the photo uploaded first and saved in database and I assign the id in the nested form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the `url`, I'd have to specify exactly where its from? Since I'm using paperclip, there's no typical or default url that paperclip uses to pass to dropzone? What about `/model` or `/model/field_name` or if I'm nested: `/project/project_images/photo`.  Also I'm thinking of a same idea for the `paramName`, would it be like `model[field_name]`? or in this case if I'm nested, `model[nested_model_attribute][field_name]`? so `project[project_images_attributes][photo]`? Or because my field has `photo[]`, its `photo[]`? I want to be able to try to do this without putting dropzone class in the form

Comment: Actually what I am thinking is your understanding about `dropzone` is wrong. Actually it only handles frontend so when a photo is dragged and dropped into it then it sends a `json` request to the server to save the photo. It will not work like `photo[]` and it provides you `photo_ids`, you will need to put some jquery/js hack into it.

Comment: please help with this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056366/how-do-i-render-photo-errors-with-json-using-dropzone-js-in-rails-4